# How to shift a column by one row for each new ID in R

Tags: r, reverse, lag

> Here is my data table called "stock":

```
TickerID      Date    Open    Close 
    A     1/1/2013    42.1     43.4
    A     1/2/2013    43.4     42.3
    A     1/3/2013    42.3     44.1
   AA     1/1/2013    28.7     28.9
   AA     1/2/2013    28.9     28.4
   AA     1/3/2013    28.4     29.1
  AAA     1/1/2013    61.1     62.1
  AAA     1/2/2013    62.1     63.5
  AAA     1/3/2013    63.5     64.4
```

> How can I add columns that allows each TickerID to present tomorrows open & close value? I also need to have an NA when the TickerID does not have a "next date"
>   I would like for it to look like this:

```
TickerID      Date    Open    Close  OpenTom  CloseTom
    A     1/1/2013    42.1     43.4     43.4      42.3
    A     1/2/2013    43.4     42.3     42.3      44.1
    A     1/3/2013    42.3     44.1       NA        NA
   AA     1/1/2013    28.7     28.9     28.9      28.9
   AA     1/2/2013    28.9     28.4     28.4      29.1
   AA     1/3/2013    28.4     29.1       NA        NA
  AAA     1/1/2013    61.1     62.1     62.1      63.5
  AAA     1/2/2013    62.1     63.5     63.5      64.4
  AAA     1/3/2013    63.5     64.4       NA        NA
```

> Here is the code I am trying:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(stock)){
    if(stock[i,"TickerID"]==NYSE[i-1,"TickerID"]){
         stock[i,"CloseTom"] <- stock[i+1,"Close"]
         stock[i,"OpenTom"] <- stock[i+1,"Open"]
     }
}
```

> How can I speed this code up so I can use it on 300,000+ rows?
>
> Note: I do not need to check to see if the next row has the next date, I know this to be true

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. OpenTom and CloseTom are basicly the same columns as Open and Close. Close simply has a lag of 1 and they have some missing values so:

```
Stock$OpenTom <- Stock$Close
Stock$CloseTom <- c(Stock$Close[2:length(Stock$Close)],NA)
```

Then find the last occuring value of TickerID. !duplicated() find the first unique element, so you can apply this to the reverse of the column and reverse it back again.

```
lastday <- rev(!duplicated(rev(Stock$TickerID)))
```

Then simply replace these IDs with NA

```
Stock$OpenTom[which(lastday)] <- NA
Stock$CloseTom[which(lastday)] <- NA

Stock
#  TickerID         Date Open Close OpenTom CloseTom
#1        A 0.0004967710 42.1  43.4    43.4     42.3
#2        A 0.0002483855 43.4  42.3    42.3     44.1
#3        A 0.0001655903 42.3  44.1      NA       NA
#4       AA 0.0004967710 28.7  28.9    28.9     28.4
#5       AA 0.0002483855 28.9  28.4    28.4     29.1
#6       AA 0.0001655903 28.4  29.1      NA       NA
#7      AAA 0.0004967710 61.1  62.1    62.1     63.5
#8      AAA 0.0002483855 62.1  63.5    63.5     64.4
#9      AAA 0.0001655903 63.5  64.4      NA       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr`:

```
dat %>% group_by(TickerID) %>% mutate(OpenTom = ifelse(Date != max(Date),Close,NA),
    CloseTom = ifelse(Date != max(Date),Close[2:3],NA))
```